# Using case with one or more symbols

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm still having problems to really grasp `case`. I have understood that you provide symbols which are internally compared using `eq`, but I'm not sure if I have gotten one thing correctly:

I have seen that I can write, e.g.:

```
(case n
  (23 'foo)
  (42 'bar)
  (otherwise 'something-else))
```

I can also write:

```
(case n
  ((23 42) 'foo-or-bar)
  (otherwise 'something-else))
```

So am I right that if I specify a list that `case` then checks whether the variable `n` matches *one of the list's elements*, but if I specify a single value, then `case` directly matches this value?

In other words: Is it okay to use the non-list version if I only have a single value?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Go to the lisp prompt and enter something in, like `(let ((n 3)) (case n ((2 3) 'foo) (4 'bar)))`. But, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Keys are conceptually lists of keys**

Conceptually each clause uses a list of keys. The test-key will be compared against each key in the keylist.

The key list `(foo bar baz)` is exactly `(foo bar baz)`.

The key `foo` is thought to denote `(foo)`. It helps to write code shorter.

```
(case x
  (foo       41)
  ((bar baz) 42)))
```

**The exception of T and OTHERWISE**

Note that `otherwise` and `(otherwise)`, `t` and `(t)` are exceptions. You need to write `(otherwise)` if you want to match the symbol:

```
(case 'otherwise
  ((otherwise) 'the-symbol-otherwise)
  (otherwise   'the-otherwise-clause))
```

**EQ vs. EQL**

Also note that most comparisons in Common Lisp are done by default with `EQL`, not `EQ`. `EQ` is pointer equality, `EQL` also works for numbers and characters.

Comment: Okay, so wrt the special case of `otherwise` it may be a good idea to always use parentheses, right?

Comment: @GoloRoden: Most code doesn't use parentheses for single item keylists.

Answer (score 2):

This is not to directly answer your question but we can use lisp to see what it is doing.

If you look in the CLHS page for `case` we can see it is a macro, that means we can macroexpand it to see what it turns into

So let's take the first example

```
(case n
  (23 'foo)
  (42 'bar)
  (otherwise 'something-else))
```

This expands into

```
(LET ((#:G1246 N))
  (COND ((EQL #:G1246 '23) NIL 'FOO)
        ((EQL #:G1246 '42) NIL 'BAR)
        (T NIL 'SOMETHING-ELSE)))
```

The `#:G1246` is a gensym which we can think of as a symbol guaranteed unique by lisp..I'm gonna just rename it `tmp` for now

```
(let ((tmp n))
  (cond ((eql tmp '23) nil 'foo)
        ((eql tmp '42) nil 'bar)
        (t nil 'something-else)))
```

Also `cond` is a macro.. let's see how that expands (i've simplified it a bit like above)

```
(let ((tmp n))
  (if (eql tmp '23)
      'foo
      (if (eql tmp '42)
          'bar
          'something-else)))
```

Now we can see all the logic

Now lets expand the next one

```
(case n
  ((23 42) 'foo-or-bar)
  (otherwise 'something-else))
```

Becomes

```
(let ((tmp n))
  (if (or (eql tmp '23) (eql tmp '42))
      'foo-or-bar
      'something-else))
```

Macroexpand is damn useful. Hope this helps

Comment: That's indeed very helpful, thanks for the detailed explanation :-))

Comment: Oh and if you are using emacs with slime then the stick your cursor at the opening paren and `Ctrl + Return` This will expand into a new buffer, you can then expand the inner macros or use undo to "un-expand" them. This kind of exploratory use of macroexpand is very illuminating. (Vim with slimv will also have a keybinding but I have no idea what it is)